# How to type a decimal point not in a number

Tags: symbols, xepersian

I'm using `xepersian` package and I was trying to type `$0.\overline{1011}$`, but I noticed that the dot after 0 is not interpreted as a decimal point (The decimal sign in Persian is something like `/`). How do I make it look like a decimal sign?

To illustrate the situataion, consider the code below. The first line doesn't use the overline and outputs the correct character for decimal point, but second line output a dot instead. Third line is meant to show how decimal point character is different from $/$.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\begin{document}
    $$0.1011$$
    $$0.\overline{1011}$$
    $$0/\overline{1011}$$
\end{document}
```

Here is how the output looks like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you already tried `$0/\overline{1011}$`, where `/` would be the Persian decimal symbol?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Mico It doesn't output the exact same character.

Comment: @egreg Sure, I added an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that `xepersian` sets up a mechanism similar to ligatures (probably via a map file), so that if the period is followed by a digit it is transformed in the decimal separator. With `\overline` it fails because this command is not a digit.

I found an undocumented feature: you can use `\decimalseparator` in the cases such as this, where it is not followed by a digit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
0.1011\\
0\decimalseparator\overline{1011}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are fast! :-) I was poking around in the file `xepersian-mathsdigitspec.sty`, had come across a bunch of statements that look like typos (`\undefied` -- should probably be `\undefined`?), and a couple of callouts to a macro called `\decimalseparator`, and the following definition: `\SetMathCharDef{\decimalseparator}{\mathpunct}{OPERATORS}{"066B}`. Sure enough, in the Opentype spec `\char"066B` points to a glyph labeled "ARABIC DECIMAL SEPARATOR". I guess it's a Persian as well as an Arabic character...

Comment: @Mico `\undefied` or `\undefined` is the same, so long as they are both undefined. In LaTeX packages it's customary to use `\@undefined`. Looking in the documented code, I saw exactly the definition of `\decimalseparator` and tried it. `;-)`